# vb.net - datagridview tabbing question

Tags: .net, vb.net

when the user tabs through datagridview i want the next row to come up instead of the next column., im using vb.net express 2008. does anyone know if this is possible? i've already thoroughly researched it on google and on stackoverflow and do not see a solution

please do not answer this question unless you know for sure that you have the right solution

Comment: I may be misssing something but I don't understand the thrust of this question - do you mean **PAGING** through a datagridview? or do you mean literally the TAB key on the keyboard? If the latter, it's a client-side JavaScript problem or you need to overried the html generation set a `TabIndex` property for your controls

Comment: asking people not to answer unless they know for sure that they have the right solution isn't the best way to go about asking for help...